# Remote control's battery bay issue, no voltage at the end of circuit

Tags: batteries, remote

I have a remote which needs 6 AA batteries, I put fresh AA batteries in and I tested via volt meter and at the last battery's negative connection is showing zero reading. The same battery's positive connection is showing 6.7 v something reading.

These are AA rechargeable

I am attaching a pic as well.[image]

Comment: Something's not connected like it should be then.

Comment: So, the question is, why aren't you wearing shoes?

Comment: Should I be wearing shoes? I though carpet is not insulator of electricity....

Comment: Check that the cells are actually making contact with the holders.  Some far-east factories have an unfortunate habit of molding overly thick contact holder webs which prevent quite ordinary battery cells from making contact with the positive terminal.

Comment: @ChrisStratton : That WAS the problem! You are spot on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all the batteries are fresh (make sure you test before putting them in) then its probably an issue with the battery terminal. Either the terminal contacts are eroded from batteries being in there too long or the battery terminal has become detached from the circuit board.

If its eroded terminal contacts then I suggest wiping away any loose erosion and then using a small amount of vinegar to clean contacts.

If its a faulty connection you will need to take apart the controller. To fix, solder the battery terminal back to circuit board.

Edit: The battery terminal was detached and had to be reconnected

Comment: Its a new remote, the last connection is some spring loaded metal contacts.
The voltage reads 0 on that but on the same cell's positive contact it reads 6.7 something Volts.

Comment: Figured it out, there was a lose connection at the battery side. i fixed it

Comment: So it looks like there is a faulty connection on the negative contact. You should try taking apart controller to see if that's the case. You might not even need to solder anything but simply snap the negative lead back into place.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Hope my answer helped.

Comment: Typically the issue is at the positive side.  The negative side contact is usually springy enough to reach outside the plastic web, but the positive divot is sometimes too small.